# How to correct/improve this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am writing a blog post, which includes code snippets with repeating "import" statements. These statements look "noisy" so I decided to omit them in the rest of the post. So I am writing:

> Technical note: from now I am omitting all these "import" statements in the rest of the post for clarity.

This sentence above seems a little awkward but I don't know how to correct/improve it. What is a better way to write it?

Comment: "for clarity" is too far away from the verb it modifies when it appears at the end of the sentence. But if you move it to the front, that problem goes away: "Technical note: for clarity, all 'import' statements will be omitted ...."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I _did_ notice that "for clarity" is too far way from the vern it modifies but did not know how to correct this issue.

Comment: This question has too many possible answers to be a good fit for the SE Q&A format. *For clarity’s sake, I will omit these “imports” statements in the remainder of this posting, but you should remember that they are still needed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technical note: to improve the clarity of this post "import" statements have been omitted from this point onward.

Technical note: to improve the clarity of this post "import" statements have been removed from the remaining text.

Answer (score 1):

From now onwards, all these *import* statements will be omitted in rest of the post for clarity.

"-" is used for sarcasm

*-* is used for highlighting (used asterix there but don't know why it doesn't show)

Comment: "Asterix" won't fit in there - big guy! Did you mean "asterisk"?